# Why isn't the div animated to go to its top in this code?

Tags: jquery

I want to animate a `div` to go to its top in the click handler of an element :

```
<div id="liste_tables" class="grid condensed">
    <div style="font-size:20px;"><a href="#" data-role="icon-retour"><span class="mif-arrow-left icon"></span></a></div><br />
    <div class="row cells4">
        <div class="cell"><span class="header">Salle</span></div>
        <div class="cell colspan3"><span class="header">Tables</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cells4" style="max-height: 330px;overflow: auto;">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="grid condensed">
                <?php
                $t_salle = new Salle();
                $salles = $t_salle->lireParCritere([]);
                foreach ($salles as $key => $salle) {
                ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <div id="tile_salle_<?php echo $key; ?>" data-pk="<?php echo $salle->salle_code; ?>" class="tile-square bg-crimson fg-white">
                            <div class="tile-content"><?php echo $salle->salle_lib; ?>
                                <div class="image-container">
                                    <div class="frame"><img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMG ?>salle.jpg"/></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell colspan3">
            <div id="tables"></div> // this is the div I want to animate
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Click handler for animating the div :

```
$("#liste_tables").on("click", "div[id^='tile_salle_']", function(){ 
     listerTables($(this).attr("data-pk"));
     $("#tables").animate({scrollTop:$(this).offset().top}, "fast");
});
```

At runtime the div is not animated ! So what is wrong ?

**EDIT :**

```
<script>
function listerTables(salle_code) {

        var donne = "salle_code="+salle_code;

        var ret = $.ajax({
                data: donne,
                type: "POST",
                url:  "RestaurantReservation/ajaxListerTablesDansSalle",
                async: false
             }).responseText;

        $('#tables').html(ret);
    }
</script>
```

Ajax ajaxListerTablesDansSalle :

```
$html = '';
$critere = array();
$critere["salle_code"] = $_POST["salle_code"];
$t_table = new TableClient();
$tables = $t_table->lireParCritere($critere);
foreach ($tables as $table) {
     $html .= '<div id="table_'.$table->table_code.'" data-pk="'.$table->table_code.'" class="tile-square bg-darkPink fg-white">
                   <div class="tile-content">'.$table->table_lib.'
                        <div class="image-container">
                             <div class="frame"><img src="'.HTTP_IMG.'table.png"/></div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
               </div>';
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: what's inside `listerTables`, it might be causing some error and the next line to animate is never executed.

Comment: I edited my question to include code inside `listerTables`.

Answer (score 0):

You are scrolling, no animating. You can make something like this:

```
var self = $(this);
$("#tables").
     css('position', 'absolute').
     animate({ 
        top: self.offset().top
     }, "fast");
```

You must to set a position (fixed|absolute) to move it.

Comment: it has bad effects : some elements are displayed at the middle ! I want them displayed at the top.

Comment: change to position absolute, and be sure that `<table id="tables">` is not the contains of some relative parents. To make sure this, you can add the table just before of `</body>`

Comment: the contents are displayed outside the div !

Comment: Provide us a working fiddle. is impossible to view the behaviour. Maybe you need to change `position()` instead your `offset()` in the animate function

Comment: can you delete your answer please ?

Comment: because I modified my page so that the div is not included in the same grid as the left element of it. So there is no animation needed in that case :)